# Why Proto-Germanic *frēgō is reconstructed?

Tags: proto-germanic

Why Proto-Germanic *fr**ē**gō is reconstructed on the following forms (not *fr**a**gō PIE o-grade of *frehnaną )?

[image]

[from wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/fr%C4%93g%C5%8D)

Comment: You have violated the licence under which WIktionary is published by reproducing this without attributing it. Reproducing it is fine, but only if attributed. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/fr%C4%93g%C5%8D . This comment fixes that.

Comment: You need to also get the comment to be "locked" since comments are deletable. Which is technically impossible in SE.